# Automate Dbeaver SQL Export

Tags: syntax, export, dbeaver

Dbeaver recently pushed an update to allow you to code an export. The documentation lists the export function as

`@export {"type": "csv", "producer": {...}, "consumer": {...}, "processor": {...}}`

I'm not sure how to format this to get the code to run. The JSON text in the documentation looks like the following:

```
{
    "type": <ID of the processor>,
    "producer": {
        <producer settings>
    },
    "consumer": {
        <consumer settings>
    },
    "processor": {
        <processor-specific settings>
    },
}
```

I'm aiming to get the code to output data to a folder and file name. The associated IDs are outputFolder and outputFilePattern which belong in the consumer settings. I've tried various permutations to get this to work, but receive errors like unterminated object at outputFolder, expecting ':' at outputFolder, invalid syntax, etc. The most obvious permutation is:

`@export {"type": "csv", "producer": {}, "consumer": {"outputFolder": "C:\downloads", "outputFilePattern": "Data"}, "processor": {...}}`

This returns the error 'invalid escape sequence at column 52 path $..outputFolder'. If you don't put quotes around outputFolder it returns the same error.

https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Export-Command/#Producer-Settings

Answer (score 0):

I realise I am quite late to the party on this one.

Try changing the direction of the ""  to  a forward slash '/'  Or escape the backslash \

I have tried both and it appears to be successful in Win 11 environment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did figure this out somewhat recently. The issue now is that you're only able to export one query at a time and still need to click through the export GUI. I have filed a ticket on the Dbeaver community page.